# If $f \ge 0$ is zero a.e., then $\int_{\Bbb R}f \,\mathrm d\lambda= 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $f \geq 0$ is measurable, then $f = 0 $ almost everywhere implies $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f \,\mathrm d\lambda= 0 $.

My try

Pick Simple $\phi \leq f $. Since $f = 0 $ ae, then how can we show $\phi = 0 ?$. IF we can show this, then $\int \phi = 0 \implies \int f = 0 $ by definition.

Can someone help me ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\phi$ were not identically $0$, then there would exist a set of positive measure $E$ and a positive number $\alpha$ such that

$$x \in E \implies \phi(x) = \alpha$$

by definition of a simple function. So....?

Comment: could you explain what is the guarantee for existence of $E$ with positive measure please?

Answer (score 2):

You can write $\mathbb R=E\cup F$ as a disjoint union, where $f=0$ on $E$ and $F$ is a null set. Then
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}f=\int_Ef+\int_Ff=0.
$$
The first integral is zero because $f=0$ and the second because $F$ is a null-set.